# Submit To PDF in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a plugin or something that creates PDF files from a entered by the user form data, when it clicks on the submit button?

Answer (score 5):

if youre wanting a form filled in, then the details of that form processed and sent to you via email with a pdf attachment of the details, i had something similar a few weeks back, I couldnt find anything that would work the way i wanted, so....

I setup my form then using a custom page template I assigned that to a page, then using php and the [html2pdf class](http://www.macronimous.com/resources/Converting_HTML2PDF_using_PHP.asp) i created my pdf which was emailed as an attachment...

heres the code i used..
been minified for this page (remember to sanitize your user input).

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: FORMTOPDF
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<style>
/* STYLES FOR ERROR PLACEMENT */
label {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}
.formerror {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color : #FFCCCC;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left:10px;
}
.errortext {
  font: bold smaller sans-serif;
}
</style>
<?php 
// CREATE AN ARRAY FOR OUR ERRORS
$arrErrors = array();
// Check for FORM SUBMISSION
// using hidden form field
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='send')) 
{ 
/* ================= START FORM DATA ========================= */
    $name  = trim($_POST['name']); 
    if ($name=='') $arrErrors['name'] = 'Please provide your name.';

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    if ($email=='') $arrErrors['Email'] = 'Please provide your Email Address.';

    $comments = trim($_POST['your-comments']);
    if ($comments=='') $arrErrors['Comments'] = 'Please add your Comments.';
/* ================= END FORM DATA ========================= */ 

    if (count($arrErrors) == 0) {
        // Process form here
    /* ================= START PDF CREATION ========================= */
    $strContent = "<p>Submission from ".$name."</p>";
    $strContent.= "<p><strong>Name</strong>:".$name."</p>";
    $strContent.= "<p><strong>Email </strong>: ".$email."</p>";
    $strContent.= "<p><strong>Comments</strong> : <br />".$comments."</p>";
    /* ================= END PDF CREATION ========================= */
    // Include our HTML to PDF creator
    // FROM THEME DIRECTORY?
    require(TEMPLATEPATH.'/html2pdf/html2fpdf.php');
    $pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    // folder location of HTML file
    $fileLocation  = "wp-content/uploads/";
    // Call to the file name from the URL
    $fileName = "Form_Submission_From_".$name;
    // add the location 'wp-content/uploads/' to the fileToOpen
    $fileToOpen  = $fileLocation;
    // Then add the actual file name // form_submission.pdf
    // output should look like 'wp-content/uploads/form_submission_from_(name).pdf'
    $fileToOpen .= $fileName.".pdf";
    // Open the file with read access
    $fp = fopen($fileToOpen,"r");
    //$strContent = fread($fp, filesize($fileToOpen));
    // Close of the page
    fclose($fp);
    // Create new PDF document from the Content
    $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
    // create our PDF in the wp uploads folder
    $pdf->Output("wp-content/uploads/" .$fileName. ".pdf");
    /* ================= END PDF ========================= */

    /* ================= START EMAIL ========================= */
    $headers= "From: YourWebsite <info@yourwebsite.co.uk>\r\n\\";
    $emailSubject = "Submission from " . $name;
    $emailAdmin = "admin@yourwebsite.co.uk"; 
    $emailMessage = "Submission from ".$yourcompanyname."\n\n";
    $emailMessage.= "Company Name: ".$yourcompanyname."\n";
    $emailMessage.= "Email : ".$email."\n";
    $emailMessage.= "Comments : \n".$comments."\n\n";
    $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/".$fileName.".pdf", $target_path);
    wp_mail($emailAdmin, $emailSubject, $emailMessage, $headers, $attachments);

    // Delete our PDF from the server after email Sent
    // uncomment this to delete after email sent?
    //unlink($fileToOpen);
    /* ================= END EMAIL ========================= */

    // show thank you message if successful
    $strGood = '<div class="formerror" style="background:#FFC;">
    <h2>Thank You</h2>
    <p>Thank you for contacting us.</p>
    </div>';


    }else{

    // The error array had something in it. There was an error.
    // Start adding error text to an error string.
     $strError = '<div class="formerror"><p><img style="margin-left:10px;" src="'.get_option('home').'/wp-content/themes/mytheme/media/images/triangle_error.gif" width="16" height="16" hspace="5" alt=""><strong>Please check the following and try again:</strong></p><ul style="margin-left:50px;">';

     // Get each error and add it to the error string
     // as a list item.
     foreach ($arrErrors as $error) {
         $strError .= "<li style='list-style-type:circle;'><em>$error</em></li>";
     }
     $strError .= '</ul></div><br />';
    } 
}// NOT BEEN SUBMITTED
// show regular page with form
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h2>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</h2>
<?php 
// show errors if there is any
echo $strError; 
?>
<?php 
// show thank you if successful
echo $strGood; 
?>
<?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/your-form-page/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" value="send" name="action">
<p <?php if (!empty($arrErrors['name'])) echo ' class="formerror"'; ?>>Your Name:
<span class="errortext" style="color:#F00;">(required)</span><br>
The rest of the form below here ------ >
</form>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

thats it, once the user fills out the form, (my form had a lot more fields than this plus an upload field for files to be attached also.)

but the forms submitted, checks for required fields, if successful it will create a pdf file from the $strContent variable, then attaches this to the email to be sent using the wp_mail from wordpress.. then displays a thank you message, or else it will show and highlight any errors,

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

I found these plugins that allow posts to be emailed or downloaded as pdf's.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/create-pdf

If you are flexible, It seems possible to programmatically create posts from your form submitted by a user, then create a pdf of that post.  The posts that are created from the form could easily be assigned a particular category which is not displayed on the site.

To programmatically create, update, and delete posts, see the WordPress Function Reference, and in particular:

[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)
[wp update post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)
[wp delete post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post)

A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=create+pdf+in+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) exhibits plenty of ways to create pdf's with php.  Some hard, some less hard.  [I found this class that might get you started: "FPDF"](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin extension called Gravity PDF, that extends from Gravity Forms. It will generate a PDF from a form, and you can choose to download or email it.

Source
https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-pdf-extended/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done an exhaustive search of the WP-plugins, but from as far as I can tell the answer is no. Of course, it would be possible to create such a plugin from scratch however the server hosting WP would need to have the proper libraries installed in order for the plugin to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

We created a custom solution for one of our clients to get this done since there weren't any ready available plugins. This system creates pdf/word documents by fetching data from Gravity Forms.

You can check out details of the solution here. [Gravity Forms to PDF/Word Document Auto-Fill Soluion](http://wisdmlabs.com/gravity-forms-pdf-word-document-automation-solution/)